# KeyError: 'Dividends'

Tags: python-3.x

for a project I was doing, I wrote

```
del sp500["Dividends"]
del sp500["Stock Splits"]
```

this resulted in an error that I could not for the life of me understand. The error was

```
# there was no match, this call should raise the appropriate
```

I am using anaconda's JuypterLab on python3

1. deleting it
2. googling it
3. restarting kernel
4. restarting anaconda
5. reinstalling yfinance (pretty sure that wasnt the issue)

Comment: Are you sure `sp500` had items with keys `"Dividends"` and `"Stock Splits"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "restarting anaconda"? Do you mean anaconda navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround would be checking if `"Dividends"` and `"Stock Splits"` are keys of `sp500` before trying to delete them:

```py
if "Dividends" in sp500.keys():
    del sp500["Dividends"]
if "Stock Splits" in sp500.keys():
    del sp500["Stock Splits"]
```

For debugging, you could also try to print `sp500` or `sp500.keys()` before the error occurs to make sure it looks like you expected.